# Dynamically Get Properties Filename in EJB Jar (deployed in ear)

Tags: jakarta-ee, parameters, ear, ejb-3.1

When creating/deploying war files, I use a  in my web.xml to define which property file to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>PropertiesFile</param-name>
        <param-value>/path/to/my.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <display-name>MyServlet</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.my.company.MyServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and use that in my servlet's init method so that I don't have to hardcode the filename in my code:

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException
{
    super.init(config);

    log.debug("Enter init()");

    // get the properties location from web.xml
    String propertiesFile = config.getServletContext()
            .getInitParameter("PropertiesFile");

    log.info("Using properties file: " + propertiesFile);

    // Finish intiliazing...
}
```

Is there something similar (or completely different) to set/get the properties file for an ear that contains an EJB jar without hardcoding it in my class? The properties file won't be included in either the jar or ear but is located on the server outside of the app server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use environment entries and inject them using `@Resource` to achieve what you want.

Take a look at this [OpenEJB example](http://openejb.apache.org/examples-trunk/injection-of-env-entry/README.html).

However, if you say something like:

> The properties file won't be included in either the jar or ear but is
>   located on the server outside of the app server.

It doesn't sound good for an enterprise application. You should not depend on resources outside of the container and not make any assumptions about resources you (or the container) can't control.
Operations on files are also discouraged (if not forbidden - don't remember exactly.)

Comment: Thanks for the link; I'll look into it.  The reason the properties files are not included in the jar/ear is because they are different depending on which sytem we are deploying to (e.g. lab, prod). The reason to use properties files in the first place is because they can change.  Which version of the properties do you include, lab or prod? And what if you accidentally overwrite the prod properties with lab because of a redeploy of the app?

Comment: @sdoca just consider it as "you've been warned" post :-) By the way - does your lab/prod properties are changed by some other process than your application and that's why you cannot include it in your application?

Comment: So, based on the link you provided, I got it to work. Thanks!  I had a Singleton class in my jar already that contained the constants for the different property keys used, so that was a natural fit to put the `@Resource` for the file path.  I created method to load the properties and annotated it with the `@PostConstruct` annotation and annotated the class with the `@Startup` annotation to ensure it was loaded.

Comment: Great, that sounds very reasonable :-)

Comment: My application reads the properties file, it doesn't set them.  Consider myself warned.  Although, I've used external properties files for years and years for my web/war applications without issue, so I think I'm safe. :)